# How can I reference a list initialized in a function? (Python)

Tags: python, list, function, reference, variable-assignment

The error I'm receiving is local variable 'actions' referenced before assignment. I have a feeling that this is because I am creating the list within the function and then trying to reference it within. This is the specific code from which I receiving the error.

```
if node.state == target:
            actions: []
            cells: []

            while node.parent is not None:
                actions.append(node.action)
                cells.append(node.state)
                node = node.parent
```

This is more context for the origin of the code I am writing.

```
def shortest_path(source, target):

    """
    Returns the shortest list of (movie_id, person_id) pairs
    that connect the source to the target.

    If no possible path, returns None.
    """
    # Create a frontier
    frontier = QueueFrontier()

    # Initialise explored set
    explored = set()
    # Create a start Node
    node = Node(state=source, parent=None, action=None)
    # Start with the source as a node (The initial state) and add it to the frontier
    frontier.add(node)
    # Start looping until we get a solution
    while True:
        # Check if Frontier is empty then no solution
        if frontier.empty():
            raise Exception("No path found")
        # Remove node from the frontier
        node = frontier.remove()
        # Check if node contains the goal state
        if node.state == target:
            actions: []
            cells: []

            while node.parent is not None:
                actions.append(node.action)
                cells.append(node.state)
                node = node.parent
            actions.reverse()
            cells.reverse()
            solution = (actions, cells)
            return solution
```

I really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You need to initialize array as `actions = []` and `cells = []`.

Comment: That's really embarrassing. Too much time staring at that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `=` to assign

```py
if node.state == target:
    actions = []
    cells = []

    while node.parent is not None:
        actions.append(node.action)
        cells.append(node.state)
        node = node.parent
```